# Maximize sum of Rayleigh quotients

Tags: optimization

I want to maximize the sum of Rayleigh quotients:

$$\max_x\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x^\top A_i x}{x^\top B_i x}$$

where $A_i$ and $B_i$ is positive definite. I've found a similar question here:
[minimization problem: sum of Rayleigh quotients](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5232/minimization-problem-sum-of-rayleigh-quotients?newreg=ce231f04d6284e5281deee8c7c1db53a). But it only deals with the case $n=2$, and therefore it seems that the methods there are not applicable for my problem.

Is there any suggestion for this problem? Does gradient descent/ascent work for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Since the sum of convex function is convex, I think that the same methods apply here.

Comment: @nicoguaro: Note that this problem is a maximization problem, so you really want the objective function to be concave. Convexity won't help here. If it were a minimization problem, the property you cite would be useful.

Comment: @GeoffOxberry, sorry, my bad.